# Not enough memory for GMRES

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

After realizing that Gauss-Seidel is extremely slow for my simulation, i wanted to try GMRES and luckily found the C++ code [here](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/richardsonm/cpp.pdf) without diving into the theory. The size of the matrix in my case is `nxn` where `n=50,000`. However, I even cannot initialize the matrix to zero because the computer freezes while initializing it. Is there a memory friendly version of GMRES?

Comment: You can just replace all instances of "A*v" in that code by a callback to "your code", which computes this matrix vector product (and uses a more appropriate representation of "A" internally). Many of the common numerical C++ frameworks (like PETSc or Trilinos) will also have implementations of GMRES. However, if you are interested in this sort of answer, please ask on [scicomp.se] instead. People "closer associated" to these frameworks are active there, and they would probably correct misleading answers (which probably won't happen here, even if you get answers).

Comment: While computing the vector product, you might also consider using your existing Gauss-Seidel as a preconditioner, because the memory consumption of GMRES is proportional to the number of GMRES iterations (once you avoid the "obvious" mistakes).